# Makefile error : duplicate symbol _main in

Tags: c, makefile

I can compile my two files serveur.c and client.c separately but when I try to use a makefile, it shows me an error. What I want is very simple : two compiled files : serveur.o and client.o.

Here is the code when I compile my two files separately :

```
gcc -lpthread serveur.c -o serveur.o
```

And

```
gcc -lpthread client.c -o client.o
```

Here is my makefile :

```
chatroom: serveur.o client.o
    gcc serveur.o client.o -o chatroom 

serveur.o: serveur.c
    gcc -lpthread serveur.c -o serveur.o

client.o: client.c
    gcc -lpthread client.c -o client.o
```

And here is the error when I write : "make -f makefile" in the terminal

```
gcc serveur.o client.o -o chatroom 
duplicate symbol _main in:
    serveur.o
    client.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [chatroom] Error 1
```

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: You need to add `-c` to the two `.o` rules to tell `gcc` to stop at the compilation stage.

Comment: That's not going to help if OP has two `main` routines defined.

Comment: @EtanReisner when I add -c I get : `gcc serveur.o client.o -o chatroom 
ld: can't link with a main executable file 'client.o' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [chatroom] Error 1`

Comment: @CarlNorum Although the two files have a main(), can I do a makefile to compile those two files ?

Comment: @Danvdb, sure, but you can't link them together. What would it mean to do so?

Comment: You can compile the files, but as soon as you try to link them together you'll get a linker error. You can't have two `main` functions. In fact, you can't have multiple definitions of any non-inline function.

Comment: You'll need two targets, one for your server executable, one for your client executable. You can't make one executable for them both if they're two separate programs. Also, specifying `-lpthread`, or any other library, should be done at the linking stage, not the compilation stage.

Answer (score 2):

If you successfully managed to build the two separate parts into a program each, it implies that both of the source files contain a `main()` or `main(int, char*[])`. However, you can have only one `main()` function per program (the restriction that you can have each function defined just once actually applies to all functions).

If each of the two files contains a complete program it is unlikely that you can just link them together: aside from the duplicate `main()` each of the programs will have some set up and some control. That is, simply getting rid of one of the `main()` functions is unlikely to result in a working program.

If you just added a `main()` function to one of the sources because otherwise it wouldn't "compile", you'll need to get rid of this `main()` and make sure that you actually *compile* the code into object files by passing the `-c` option. You'd leave the `-c` option off when *linking* the code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is some missunderstanding in the way compiler, assembler and linker work in creating an executable.

The usual convention is to give the .o extension to object files generated after the assembler stage not to executables!

As gcc will act as compile, assemble and link manager performing all steps in one run without beeing told to stop at an earlier stage, `gcc -lpthread serveur.c -o serveur.o` and
`gcc -lpthread client.c -o client.o` will both create executables not object files.

To make gcc stop after the assembly stage you have to pass it the `-c` switch. `gcc -c serveur.c` and `gcc -c client.c`. In this case giving `-o serverveur.o` and `-o client.o` is not necessary, as gcc will use them by default.

To link the generated object files the last thing to do would be `gcc -lpthread serveur.o client.o -o chatroom`

A Makefile to accomplish all that could look like that:

```
chatroom: serveur.o client.o
    gcc -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

Unfortunately this will still not fix your problem of having two definitions of a main() function, one in serveur.c and one in client.c.

As `gcc -lpthread serveur.c -o serveur.o` and `gcc -lpthread client.c -o client.o` would have been rejected by the linker with an unresolved reference to main without, I am quite sure both of your sources contain a definition.

If instead of building one executable all you wanted to do is have make create two executables, `serveur` and `client` for you, your Makefile should look something like this.

```
.PHONY: all

all: serveur client
```